# Unable to send raw transaction

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, cpp-ethereum, raw-transaction

i'm working on to the morden testnet and using a nodejs application i wrote (using ethereumjs-util, ethereumjs-tx) i'm trying to push a raw tx on to the testnet.

I've tested GETH "eth.sendRawTransaction" without success, it keeps saying there is no balance or no account installed, even if i'm pushing a raw tx.. there is no point on checking the presence of balance or wallet/account, anyway i installed eth.

I've got an ethereum node backed by "eth", currently synced.
I'm using Geth and ethconsole to interface to the eth process via ipc/rpc.

I'm using my NodeJS app just to sign the TX, than i manually push the raw tx using geth or ethconsole, but the TX is not sent.

```
> eth.sendRawTransaction('f87a831001888504a817c800830493e09454a25919a915bbaeb58a96679428f80d733af89392313030303030303030303030303030303030801ca0ecd622603d87d290b7440a8a03413d865dd67783e90cde0ef33d3f5752888ffda031adeee357777c7c39f3edb8920c91aec0cced05ad429d8aa4be627604bd820b');

> "0x42fbb8e551be1aaefd6d768d7798467d7978e3d06e0dd3db20f88e5b14387328"

> eth.getTransaction("0x42fbb8e551be1aaefd6d768d7798467d7978e3d06e0dd3db20f88e5b14387328")

> null
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe you need to use canonical hex representation:

```
eth.sendRawTransaction('**0x**f87a831001888504a817c800830493e09454a25919a915bbaeb58a96679428f80d733af89392313030303030303030303030303030303030801ca0ecd622603d87d290b7440a8a03413d865dd67783e90cde0ef33d3f5752888ffda031adeee357777c7c39f3edb8920c91aec0cced05ad429d8aa4be627604bd820b');
```